# Python shutil.copytree function not working

Tags: python, copy, shutil, copytree

I feel like I am either missing something basic here are something wonky is going on. I have read the docs and understand that copytree must specify both a source path and a destination path. I am struggling with the destination part. My code is below...

```
from shutil import copytree


copytree("C:\Users\D34DLYHAX\Pictures", "C:\Users\D34DLYHAX\Pictures\Temp\\")
```

The tree is copied without any troubles; however, the folder "Temp" is not being created and the copied tree is not being placed inside of it. Instead, the copied tree is placed at "C:\Users\D34DLYHAX\Pictures\My Pictures." Why is this happening? Unless I have read the documents incorrectly, shouldn't the copied tree be inserted in Temp with Temp as the source folder?

Thanks for your help and answers.

--Okay, now it is getting stranger still. When I go to view the copied folder it is named "My Pictures," no problems there. However, if I throw the copied tree into the recycling bin and view the contents of the recycling bin the copied tree is now named "Temp". What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what the issue was, but this seems to be working just fine...

```
from datetime import date
from shutil import copytree


currentDate = str(date.today())
currentDate = currentDate.replace("-", ".")
DESTINATION = "C:\\Users\\D34DLYHAX\\Desktop\\Backup " + currentDate

copytree("C:\\Users\\D34DLYHAX\\Pictures\\", DESTINATION + "\\My Pictures")
```

Comment: This is the correct "solution" not sure it is an answer though as to what was wrong with the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution is to use forward slashes. I suspect you are not escaping things correctly.

```
from shutil import copytree
copytree("C:/Users/D34DLYHAX/Pictures", "C:/Users/D34DLYHAX/Pictures/Temp")
```

Or leave off the trailing `//`

```
from shutil import copytree
copytree("C:\Users\D34DLYHAX\Pictures", "C:\Users\D34DLYHAX\Pictures\Temp")
```

**Another thing that might cause you a disaster is copying a folder inside itself. Don't do that, think about how it could go wrong. Copy it outside itself.**

Remember if you want symplinks copied pass `symlinks=True`

Comment: I changed the code to this: 

from shutil import copytree
copytree("C:/Users/D34DLYHAX/Pictures", C:/Users/D34DLYHAX/Documents/Temp")

and am still getting the same results as previously mentioned -__-